# Using jquery slide panels and javascript lightbox together causing conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some jQuery to have some sliding panels. It's for a portfolio website I'm building for myself. I have a panel sliding in that contains thumb nails that I want to link to images to be displayed inside of a Lightbox using JavaScript.

When all the scripts are inside my head, the sliding panels work but the Lightbox does not.
If I remove the jQuery script link from my head in order to "temporarily disable the sliding panels the Lightbox works properly. I'm assuming that I have some sort conflict, but I am new to jQuery and JavaScript so I don't even know where to begin.

Heres my code inside my head tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/lightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js1/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1/slidepanels.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include JQuery before Prototype, and then switch it into [NoConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

After this,  load Prototype / Scriptaculous and see if that works.

Comment: Still having troubles, i tried putting it into no conflict mode maybe I did it wrong. But I took out all the lightbox.js stuff and just added the no conflict stuff in and my sliding panels stop working.

I added jQuery.noConflict(document).ready(function($){

Answer (score 0):

pfff why do u use jquery+prototype? they do almost the same things. better to find jquery lightbox and remove prototype. or use prototype, but not both.

Comment: "I'm assuming that I have some sort conflict, but I am new to jQuery and JavaScript so I don't even know where to begin."
^^^^^^^^^
Because I wasn't aware they do almost the same things.. maybe you missed the sentence where I said I was new to jquery/javascript? 
But thanks for correcting me.

Comment: prototype like audi. jquery like bmw. now you use both car to ride, but you can use 1 :) they do the same thing but in different way. google for "jquery lightbox" and remove prototype from project.

Comment: Ok, Ill use a jquery lightbox instead. Im in graphic design school, and Im trying to not be another graphic designer who doesnt know anything about coding. :p